# Proof conditional probability formula

Tags: probability, random-variables

a question for my homework for probability goes as follows:
Given X,Y,U, three discrete random variables, prove the following:

$$
p_{X|Y}(i|j) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_{X|YU}(i|j,k)p_{U|Y}(k|j)
$$

The same formula is also asked when X,Y en U are continous:

$$
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X|YU}(x|y,u)f_{U|Y}(u|y)du
$$

I think this is done by using the multiplication rule or the law of total probability but I'm turning in circles...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $p_{X\mid Y, U}(i\mid j, k)$ is a _probability_ of some kind. So, _what_ is it the probability **of**?

Comment: $p_{X|Y,U}$ is the probability mass function of X given Y and U

Comment: No, don't tell me about functions, which is a word whose meaning I do not understand. $p_{X\mid Y, U}(\mid j, k)$ is a _number,_  say $0.0347$, that is a probability of some kind. What _kind?_ and what _event_ is $0.0347$ the probability **of?** Your response needs to be something like $P(A) = 0.0347$ or $P(A\mid B) = 0.0347$ where **you** need to replace $A$ and $B$ by something that might be stated in terms of $X, Y, U$ and possibly $i, j, k$.

Comment: There is no event given, these are not defined probability mass functions or density functions. I don't really know were you are heading with those questions?

Comment: Do you have, in your notes, or in your textbook, or even on the problem set you are working on, a _definition_ of probability mass function? Not the name "probability mass function", or the _abbreviation_ "pmf", or the notation "$p_X(a)$", but what it all means? If your _definition_ says that $p_X(a)$ **equals** something, tell us **what** it equals. If your definition says "The probability mass function (pmf) of a discrete random variable is $p_X(a)$." and stops there without further elucidation, then I do not think I will be able to help you further.

Comment: $p_{X}(a) = Prob[X = a] $
as an example. The probabiltiy mass function is the function that associates a number between 0 and 1 that is the probability of the event that X = a

Comment: Good! Now, let's try and figure out what _events_ $A$ and $B$ are meant when we use $p_{U\mid Y}(k\mid j)$ as an expression for $P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: $p_{U|Y}(k|j) = Prob[U=k|Y=j]$ or in words the probability of U = k given that Y = j

Comment: Better!  Now, $\Pr(U=k\mid Y = j)$ is a _conditional_ probability, and as such is _defined_ to be the ratio of two (unconditonal) probabilities $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. That is, $$Pr(U=k\mid Y = j) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}.$$ What are the _events_ $A$ and $B$?

Comment: A : $ U = k$  and $ Y = j $
B : $ Y = j $

Comment: Better and better. So now you have that $$p_{U\mid Y}(k\mid j) = \Pr(U=k \mid Y = j) = \frac{\Pr(\{U=k\}\cap\{Y=j\})}{\Pr(\{Y=j\})}.$$ Can you write down a similar expression for $p_{X\mid Y, U}(i\mid j, k)$ without additional help and prompting? Hint: the numerator will be the probability of the intersection of _three_ events,_ the denominator the probability of the intersection of two events.

Comment: I think it's:
$$
p_{X|Y,U}(i|j,k) = \frac{Pr(\{X=i\} \cap [\{Y=j\} \cap \{U=k\}])}{Pr(\{Y=j\}\cap\{U=k\})}
$$

Comment: You are nearly there. Combine the two expressions that you have so diligently worked out to state what ratio of probabilities $p_{X\mid Y, U}(i \mid j,k)p_{U\mid Y}(k \mid j)$ works out to be. If you remember that $\Pr(C \cap D) = \Pr(D \cap C)$, you may be able to cancel some terms. If you do get something of the form $\frac{\Pr(E \cap F \cap G)}{\Pr(H)}$, see if you can sum the resulting expression from $k = 0$ to $\infty$. (Hint: $\Pr(H)$ does not depend on $k$ at all and so can be pulled out as a constant so that you are just summing $\Pr(E \cap F \cap G)$ from $k=0$ to $\infty$.)

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
      p_{X|Y,U}(i|jk)p_{U|Y}(k|j) &= \frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y = j \cap U = k)}{Pr(Y=j\cap U=k)}\frac{Pr(U=k\cap Y=j)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
&= \frac{Pr(X=i\cap Y=j \cap U=k)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
\end{align}
$$
sum both sides with $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} $
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_{X|Y,U}(i|jk)p_{U|Y}(k|j) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
&= \frac{1}{Pr(Y=j)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)\\
&= \frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
&= Pr(X=i|Y=j)\\
&= p_{X|Y}(i|j) 
\end{align}
$$
I assume this is correct?

Comment: Yes!!!  Now, please copy your calculation above into an _Answer_ (yes, you are not just permitted but actually encouraged to post an Answer to your own Question, and even _Accept_ it as the best answer if you wish). That way, this Question will not remain in the Unanswered category and be thrown up repeatedly as one of the top questions of the day.

Comment: All right! Thanks a lot, I really understand this question now! Your way of answering really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p_{U|Y}(k|j)$ is a conditional probability:
$$
p_{U|Y}(k|j) = Pr(U=k|Y=j) = \frac{Pr(U=k \cap Y=j)}{Pr(Y=j)}
$$
$p_{X|Y,U}(i|j,k)$ is also a conditional probability:
$$
\frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)}{Pr(Y=j\cap U=k)}
$$
The product then becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
p_{U|Y}(k|j)p_{X|Y,U}(i|j,k) &= \frac{Pr(U=k \cap Y=j)}{Pr(Y=j)}\frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)}{Pr(Y=j\cap U=k)}\\
&= \frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
\end{align}
$$
Summing both sides with $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ yields:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_{U|Y}(k|j)p_{X|Y,U}(i|j,k) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
&= \frac{1}{Pr(Y=j)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}Pr(X=i \cap Y=j \cap U=k)\\
&= \frac{Pr(X=i \cap Y=j)}{Pr(Y=j)}\\
&= Pr(X=i|Y=j) = p_{X|Y}(i|j)
\end{align}
$$
The variable U is 'summed out', and the last step follows again from conditional probability. The continuous case is solved in an analog way.